# Unicode_escape_decode() takes no arguments error when run python in F#

Tags: python, f#

To run python script with F#, got error,

if just run the python script, it do not have error, however put it in F#, it has error or run a very long time

In order to solve error Unicode_escape_decode() takes no arguments

I convert to ASCII and got the same error

Then add code

```
import codecs
def my_unicode_escape_decode(x):
    return x
codecs.unicode_escape_decode = my_unicode_escape_decode
```

In the script to be run, it runs a very long time, have not ever stoppped since run let scoperesult = script.Execute(scope)

```
let engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    let paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();

    paths.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages");
    paths.Add(@"C:\Python27");
    paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
    engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);

    let scope = engine.CreateScope();

    let MatrixString = ""
    let numberofvariables = 2
    let numberofvariablestring = numberofvariables.ToString()

    let unicodeString = String.Format("import codecs
def my_unicode_escape_decode(x):
    return x
codecs.unicode_escape_decode = my_unicode_escape_decode
import sys 
from sympy import *
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy.abc import x, y, z, f, a, b
from sympy import *
f = Symbol('f')
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
z = Symbol('z')
varlist = [x,y,z,a,b]
A = Matrix([[1,0],[0,1]])
result = A")
    let ascii : Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
    let unicode : Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    let unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString);
    let asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, unicodeBytes);
    let asciiString = String(asciiBytes |> ascii.GetChars)

    let script = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(asciiString)
    let scoperesult = script.Execute(scope)
    Console.WriteLine(scope.GetVariable("result"))
```

**update:**

if run the script with python, it do not have error.

After add async, it has error when run in F#

Additional information: 'ScopeStorage' object has no attribute 'my_unicode_escape_decode'

After run a long time, it has error finally.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll

Additional information: 'module' object has no attribute '_getframe'

to see this , need to delete async

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    let paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();

    paths.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages");
    paths.Add(@"C:\Python27");
    paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
    engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);

    let scope = engine.CreateScope();

    let MatrixString = ""
    let numberofvariables = 2
    let numberofvariablestring = numberofvariables.ToString()

    let unicodeString = String.Format("import codecs
def my_unicode_escape_decode(x):
    return x
codecs.unicode_escape_decode = my_unicode_escape_decode
import sys 
from sympy import *
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy.abc import x, y, z, f, a, b
from sympy import *")
    let ascii : Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
    let unicode : Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    let unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString);
    let asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, unicodeBytes);
    let asciiString = String(asciiBytes |> ascii.GetChars)

    let script = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(asciiString)
    let scoperesult = script.Execute(scope)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(scope.GetVariable("my_unicode_escape_decode"))
```

Comment: Why exactly are you using F# to generate python?  Also, could you be more clear on the problem - is it with the F# or the python?

Comment: it is using F# to run the python script

Comment: So what exactly is the error?

Comment: if run the script with python, it do not have error.

After add async, it has error when run in F#

Additional information: 'ScopeStorage' object has no attribute 'my_unicode_escape_decode'

After run a long time, it has error finally.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll

Additional information: 'module' object has no attribute '_getframe'

to see this , need to delete async

Comment: you should stop putting random piece of codes together until you get the expected result. `async` does not work like that, once you create the async object you have to execute it. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233250.aspx)

Comment: i mentioned to delete this async, the real error is An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll

Additional information: 'module' object has no attribute '_getframe'