# C#, IronPython, and Sympy: unicode_escape_decode() takes no arguments

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, sympy

I am trying to create a static method for simplifying mathematical expressions in sympy using IronPython from C#. I have already been able to test and confirm the execution of simple python statements from IronPython. The problem is when I attempt to run the code below, I get the following error:

```
unicode_escape_decode() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

I have looked online for an explanation and managed to find another user with the same problem but it doesn't seem to be resolved:
[Unicode_escape_decode() takes no arguments error when run python in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22472669/1445054)

Here is my code below:

```
public static MathExpression SimplifyExpression(MathExpression Input)
    {
        //Make sure the mathematics engine is initialized
        if (!MathEngine.IsInitialized()) throw new Exception("Unable to simplify expression...the mathematics engine isn't initialized!");

        //Convert the MathExpression object into a sympy string
        string SympyString = Input.ToSympyString();

        //Analyze the input for variables
        List<Variable> Variables = Input.GetContainedVariables();
        if (Variables == null) return Input;
        if (Variables.Count < 1) return Input;

        //Strings used
        string NL = "\n";
        //string NL = Environment.NewLine;
        string SympyScript = string.Empty;

        //Import the required libraries
        SympyScript += "from sympy import *" + NL;
        SympyScript += "import clr" + NL;
        SympyScript += "from System import String" + NL + NL;

        //Create the neccessary variables
        foreach (Variable v in Variables)
        {
            SympyScript += String.Format("{0} = symbols('{0}')", v.ToSympyString()) + NL;
        }
        SympyScript += NL;

        //Set the new variable "expr" as the expression string
        SympyScript += "expr = " + SympyString + NL;
        SympyScript += "expr_simp = simplify(expr)" + NL;

        //Convert the sympy expression back into a string
        SympyScript += "result = clr.Convert(expr_simp, System.String)" + NL;

        //Execute the script
        var TempScope = MathEngine.PythonEngine.CreateScope();
        var ExecutionScript = MathEngine.PythonEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(SympyScript);
        ExecutionScript.Execute(TempScope);
        //MathEngine.Execute(SympyScript);

        //Obtain the simplified string after the script is executed
        string SimplifiedString = TempScope.GetVariable("result");

        //Convert the simplified sympy string back into a MathExpression object
        var expression = SympyStringToExpression(SimplifiedString);

        //Return the result
        return expression;
    }
```

It is important to note that "MathEngine.PythonEngine" points to a Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine object

The following are my search paths:

```
C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages
C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib
```

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**
Like the other question referenced above, I tried my crack at adding the following lines to the top of my python script:

```
import codecs
def my_unicode_escape_decode(x):
    return x
codecs.unicode_escape_decode = my_unicode_escape_decode
```

Unlike the asker of that question however, it seems to work at first after running for a *VERY* long time until it finally stops and throws the error:

```
name 'System' is not defined
```

I will continue to look for possible solutions to the problem but it seems as though sympy just isn't compatible with IronPython at its current version (and vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

Here is your error:

```
SympyScript += "result = clr.Convert(expr_simp, String)" + NL;
//SympyScript += "result = clr.Convert(expr_simp, System.String)" + NL;
```

Find also my complete demo [here](https://giuliohome.wordpress.com/2015/05/03/79/)