# sympy import error in IronPython 2.7

Tags: python, ironpython, sympy

I'm trying to use the sympy library in my python script, but I'm getting an error when I try to import it. How do I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library you are using seems to make use of an internal API to get information of the current stack/live objects.
In order to provide the required information and interfaces you have to run IronPython with the `-X:FullFrames` argument.

Should you plan on hosting IronPython from C# [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6999692/468244) explains the necessary steps.

Instead of the previous situation/error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7>ipy
IronPython 2.7.5 (2.7.5.0) on .NET 4.0.30319.42000 (32-bit)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys._getframe(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_getframe'
```

you will get the expected behavior

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7>ipy -X:FullFrames
IronPython 2.7.5 (2.7.5.0) on .NET 4.0.30319.42000 (32-bit)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys._getframe(0)
<frame object at 0x000000000000002B>
```

Comment: I get the following error on running ipy with -X:FullFrames:
http://imgur.com/6vA8LfB

Comment: Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683868/c-ironpython-and-sympy-unicode-escape-decode-takes-no-arguments) related?